# Oracle APEX Open modal page through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to open a modal page with Javascript using this code:

```
var purl = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:2131:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.:2131:P2131_ID:&P2109_RSLT.:2131';
apex.navigation.redirect (purl);
```

but i get an error for the checksum:
[image]

if i use a DA to open this page, it works without this error:
[image]

The problem is with the vale if my P2109_RSLT item. First i calculate  this value and then i want to open page P2131 according to this new value of my page item. That's why i want to use a Javascript to open this page instead of a Dynamic Action

Comment: If your target page cannot be opened without a checksum, you will have to generate the full url (including checksum) on server side (using `apex_page.get_url` ) and then open it on client side.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Tschernich. for your response. Can you please give me an example how can i create this url with checksum, because i am newbie...